# factor $29$ into irreducible elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{ 2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[ \sqrt {7}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-factorization

The statement goes as the title.
So I figured that $29 = (5+2i)(5-2i)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. However I'm not sure how to continue since the respective rings look like this:

$\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{ 2}]=\{a+bi\sqrt{2}:a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]=\{a+b\sqrt{7}:a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly used the fact that for a factorization into 2 factors in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ you need a representation of 29 as the sum of 2 squares. So for such a factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt 2]$ you need a representation of 29 as the sum $a^2+2b^2$. And for such a factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 7]$ you need a representation of 29 as the sum $a^2-7b^2$.

Comment: For the latter I can think of pair (6,1) as that would give us 36 -7=29, but the former seems irreducible since a squared has to be odd and that would make the only options 1,9,25 none of which can pair up with any other integer 2b squared to give us 29. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: Indeed any prime $p=5\bmod 8$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt 2]$. As you say, $a$ is odd, so $a^2=1\bmod 8$ so $2b^2=4\bmod 8$ so $b^2=2\bmod 4$ which doesn't happen. (Similarly, in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt 2]$, $p=7\bmod 8$ is also irreducible.)